# I have requirement for Api performance testing

Tags: jmeter

I need to achieve 6TPS for one Api.
Need to run for an 1hr. How many user load required to provide in jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your API response time

- If API response time is 1 second - you will need 6 users
- If API response time is 2 seconds - you will need 12 users
- If API response time is 0.5 seconds - you will need 3 users
- etc.

More information: [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second)

Personally I would suggest going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) configured like:

[image]

And [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) configured like this:

[image]